# How to sort numbers and write to new text file

Tags: python, sorting, external-data-source

could anyone please help me with the following problem. I have a task where I need to sort numbers from a txt file from lowest to highest value. No matter the combination of the numbers or length of text it needs to sort the numbers from lowest to highest.
Any help will really be appreciated.

Text file (input.txt)

> min:2,1,4,3,6,5
>
> max:1,2,3,4,5,6
>
> avg:1,2,3,4,5,6

I have written some code as follows but its just arranging the  line title alphabeticaly

```
inputFile = open("input.txt", 'r')
lineList = inputFile.readlines()
lineList.sort()
print (lineList)
for line in lineList:
    print(line)
    with open('inputcopy.txt', 'a') as f:
        for line in lineList:
            lineList.sort()
            f.write(line)
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: So do you want your script to ignore the non-number content of the file and just collect all the numbers that happen to be there? (i.e. 2, 1, 4, etc. but ignoring 'min:', 'max:', etc.?)

Comment: Yes please i need to add the script in the output text file afterwards but i only need to arrange the numbers

Answer (score 1):

Since you're reading data from `file`, we have every line as a string. So, you need to use `split` method in combination `int` constructor.

This can be achieved using a *list comprehension*.

```
for line in lineList:
    numbers = [int(item) for item in line.split(':')[1].split(',')]
```

`line.split(':')[1]` gives as the string `2,1,4,3,6,5`

Another `split` by *comma separator* gives us the list of `numbers`. I used `int` constructor because after `split` method we have them like `strings`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex. Note that you need to either convert to int or use a custom function that considers the integer representation

```
for line in lineList:
   sorted_line = sorted(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+',line)))


for line in lineList:
   sorted_line = sorted(re.findall(r'\d+',line), key=lambda x:int(x))
```